# Reposition label after apply transform iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I've a UILabel below the center of a UIView with a margin of 20 pixels.

---

UIView Center

UIViewCenter + 20

---

```
 self.tableNameLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.tableView.origin.x + self.tableView.frame.size.width / 2, self.tableView.origin.y + self.tableView.frame.size.height / 2 + (kTableNameMargin/ 2.f));
```

When i rotate the UIView 90º degrees i want recalculate the position of this UILabel, so that the UILabel can stay in the same place, below the center with that same margin.

The problem is when the rotation is applied, the UILabel goes to another position. For example, when i apply the 90º the label goes to the right. Any specific reason why this happens? I know this:

> Warning: If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

Any ideia how i can resolved this, so that the UIlabel can stay always down the center positioned?

Comment: Use Autolayout instead of hardcoding the frame. It looks complicated at first but is really powerful and actually easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting and calculating centre yourself why don't you use auto-layouting? In auto-layouting you can align the centre of the label with the centre of its parent view. This will remove the need of repositioning the label whenever any transformation is applied on parent view.

Now if you rotate the parent view by 90 degree then the label will also be rotated by 90 degree. To avoid this you have to rotate the label by 270 degrees as shown below

```
-(void)rotateBy90
{
    self.parentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2); // 90 degress
    self.label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI + M_PI_2); //270 degress
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that the referencial is changed too when you apply the transform. Even with the auto-layout the UILabel does not stay below the center.

Comment: Can  you post your code here? I am not able to reproduce your issue in sample application.